# xamarin forms - changing button text on all carousel content pages

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

What would be the "best" (or a better) way to do the following?

In a carousel page (say 6 content pages), I click a button, part of the action changes the text on that button, but it also has to change for all the other content pages.

I currently have this happening in the carousel pages OnCurrentPageChanged(), where I call a function and pass in "this". `helpers.ChangeAll(this);`

```
public void ChangeAll(CarouselSwipePage page)
        {
            foreach (SwipePageContent v in page.Children)
            {
                Button b = v.Content.FindByName<Button>("pause");
                if (GlobalSettings.Settings.Default.CarouselCountEnabled) //this is set elsewhere and is used to determine whether the carousel is changing automatically, if it is then set the text to pause
                {
                    b.Text = FontAwesomeFont.PauseCircleO;
                }
                else
                {
                    b.Text = FontAwesomeFont.PlayCircleO;
                }
            }
        }
```

This works ok on android but on ios when the user swipes to the next content page after clicking the button, the button text is momentarily the old value before changing to the new value, due to the function being called OnCurrentPageChanged().

Apart from that I'm sure there must be a better way to do this, it looks rubbish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a style for the buttons, and just change the text value of the style?

So, using binding properties or dynamic resources, when you change the value, it is going to change all the buttons of your application that use this style. I think this approach is pretty much better and simpler than a loop.